# Creating polygon from exterior points using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, point, polyline-creation, point-of-interest, concave-hull

How to convert points data to polygon, [image] so as to form polygon from exterior point as shown above

Answer (score 6):

I would create a geometry collection from the points using `st_collect()`:
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html

Then I would create convex hull from the point collection:
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html

If you have a table of point geometries called testpoints where geometry column name was `the_geom`, this should create the polygon that you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT st_astext(st_concavehull(st_collect(the_geom),0.99))
FROM myschema.testpoints;
```

Comment: If you are looking for a good PostGIS book, the new PostGIS Cookbook from PACKT is very good.

Comment: thanks david, your query works on a simple points, but not good enough on complex points.

Comment: Can you provide an example or define what you mean by complex points?  Multi-point features?  I am pretty sure that the query that I provided will correctly solve the problem that you diagrammed.

Comment: This my point 

<img src="http://duniabimbel.com/blog/img/files/Untitled.png">

i use concavehull with 0.5 %

Comment: I think the trick is that there is no magic solution that fits all point sets.  The computer doesn't know what you want it to look like in the end.  st_concave_hull starts with a convex hull and then 'shrink wraps' it based on your value for target percent. I would increase the value of your target percent.