# Transferring Z attributes to polygon layer in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, digitizing

I have a point layer with the z attribute (and there is a field with the same z value). I have digitised a polygon, snapping to the point layer. How can I transfer the z value from the point layer to each polygon vertex?

**Edit**

They're a bunch of points surveyed with a total station of the outline of a building, so I have connected the dots to make the actual footprint polygon, but each polygon vertex has a 0 Z attribute, and I want to transfer the Z attribute from each point to each corresponding vertex.

Comment: I'm sure I've done this before, but baby-based sleep deprivation has addled my brain somewhat!

Comment: do u mean every vertex of your polygon layer has a corresponding point in the point layer ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming your polygons are quite simple**, you could do it all in one step in Virtual Layer by combining @Gabriel De Luca's multipart-to-singlepart query [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341570/98784) and this neat shortcut for rebuilding polygons from points [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90500/98784).

Replace `pts_z` with your points layer name and `poly` with your polygon layer name.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE parts AS (
  SELECT t.id, t.total, 1 AS part
  FROM totals AS t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.total, part + 1 AS part
  FROM totals AS t
  INNER JOIN parts AS p ON t.id = p.id AND p.part < t.total
  ),

totals AS (
  SELECT id, num_points(geometry) AS total
  FROM multipoints
  ),

multipoints AS (
  SELECT id, nodes_to_points(geometry) AS geometry
  FROM poly
  ),

polypoints AS (
  SELECT p.id, p.part, geometry_n(m.geometry,p.part) AS geometry
  FROM parts AS p
  INNER JOIN multipoints AS m ON p.id = m.id
),

polypoints_z AS (
  SELECT pp.id, pp.part, st_translate(pp.geometry,0,0,st_z(pz.geometry)) AS geometry, st_z(pz.geometry) AS zval 
  FROM polypoints AS pp
  INNER JOIN pts_z AS pz ON intersects(pp.geometry,pz.geometry)
  ORDER BY id, part
)

SELECT id, st_convexhull(st_collect(geometry)) AS geometry
FROM polypoints_z
GROUP BY id
```

---

**Step 1** (`multipoints`): Extract the nodes from the polygon features along with the original polygon `id`

**Step 2** (`totals` and recursive function `parts`): Figure out how many nodes each polygon has and generate a series of numbers accordingly per polygon (5 nodes = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; 3 nodes = 1, 2, 3...)

**Step 3** (`polypoints`): Convert `multipoints` to single points by iterating over each geometry part using step 2

**Step 4** (`polypoints_z`): Then as @snaileater suggested you perform a spatial join on `polypoints` and your points layer, joining the points' z value and adding it to the polygon nodes using `ST_Translate()`

**Step 5**: Finally, use `ST_Collect()` to regroup all the points in `polypoints_z` by the original polygon `id`, resulting in a multipoint geometry, and use `ST_ConvexHull()` to create the polygon by 'shrink-wrapping' around that geometry.

**Step 5 won't work properly if you have more complex polygons** - where you have a point sticking inwards, for example.

I'm sure there is a way to rebuild the polygon using `id` and `part`, rather than Convex Hull, but I can't get `Make_Line()` to work on multipointZs in QGIS Virtual Layer...

---

Example:

Polygons with `id` 1 and 2 and point layer with z values shown.

[image: example1]

Result from Virtual Layer query - does not recreate polygon accurately for `id` 2 due to more complex geometry.

[image: example2]

However Z-values have been transferred across to polygon vertices if you inspect the geometry (here in DB Manager).

[image: example3]

Comment: Thanks she_weeds, although that seems exceptionally complicated! Definitely something to wrap up in a script.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of an easy out of the box way of doing this but I have one idea. You could firstly convert your points (which contain the Z value) to a raster, ensuring you choose a suitable scale. Then use the Drape tool over your newly created building outline to set the Z value for each of the polygons vertices.

Comment: Thanks @AWGIS. I thought about that, but it seems a bit messy. I'll give it a go though and see if it works. Otherwise I see a day of plugin development ahead of me :)

Comment: @MerseyViking there is definitely a good use case for a tool that achieves this

Comment: @MerseyViking Hi did you managed to do it? I have a same problem

Comment: @LEI I've moved on to other things since then, but I don't think I ever got a satisfactory way of doing it. IIRC, I just did it manually in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you try the following *'vector-only'* three steps process :

1) **Extract vertices** (by any means, u can use Vector geometry/Extract vertices in the **Processing toolbox**

2) Make a **spatial join** between these vertices and your point layer, that will enable you to retrieve your z values

3) **Rebuild the polygons** *(that should not be hard with the table generated by the Extract vertices treatment)* ...

Tell me if it works ...

Comment: Thanks snaileater. While manually rebuilding the polygons in this case isn't too taxing, it'd be a tedious task on larger datasets.

Comment: Why do u say that ? i never implied **manual** rebuilding ...

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood.